# How to position item, Qpixmap, Qstring in a QGraphicScene/QGraphicView in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I add a Qpixmap and a string into QgraphicScene and then setScene into QgraphicView. 
This Qpixmap and string stay in the middle of the QgRaphicScene. How can i change the position of these? Can i use layout manager for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`QGraphicsItem::setPos`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos) function to set the position of an item.

Comment: Can i use layout manager inside a QGraphicsene? it's better to use absolute positioning right?

Comment: @user2534154 This depends of what you want to do. You can use one of [`QGraphicsLayout`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QGraphicsLayout.html)s subclasses to set a layout in your scene. Whichever fits your needs.